# Shell Script automatically exits from SSH section after switching of user (through pbrun command)

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, su

I have the below piece of code..

```
ssh some_user@server << EOF
echo 'Successfully connected to the server'
pbrun previlige -u user
ls
pwd
id
...few more commands
EOF
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
     echo 'Successful Execution of the last command in ssh'
fi
```

Now the issue that I face in the above code is, the script automatically exits after switching user through the **pbrun** command (i.e. it never executes the **ls**, **pwd** and subsequent commands). To make things complicated, this issue is intermittent. Sometimes I get the proper output of all the subsequent commands and sometimes I don't.

**Output when the issue occurs:**

```
Successfully connected to the server 
su from some_user to user at Mon Oct 6 09:47:00  MDT 2014 
Successful Execution of the last command in ssh
```

In the above case it never displays the subsequent output of commands after switching the user

**Output when the issue doesn't occur**

```
Successfully connected to the server 
su from some_user to user at Mon Oct 6 09:47:00 MDT 2014 
Logs migrate.properties prereq.sh src_exp.sh src_mig.exp 
/home/venus/ 
uid=* gid=* groups=**** 
Successful Execution of the last command in ssh
```

Is there any cause/fix for this? Even a workaround should be fine for me..! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Passing an inner heredoc ensures that your later contents are fed to `pbrun`'s stdin, rather than invoked in the outer shell only after `pbrun` exits, which is what would happen otherwise:

```
ssh some_user@server <<'OUTER_EOF'
echo 'Successfully connected to the server'
pbrun -u user bash <<'INNER_EOF'
# this is inside both ssh and pbrun
ls
pwd
id
INNER_EOF
# this is inside ssh, but not inside pbrun
OUTER_EOF
```

Comment: Hi Charles, Thanks for your reply.! I tired the it with the inner heredoc as well..still no luck. It automatically exits after the pbrun command. The weird thing is sometimes it automatically works..Modified code after your suggestion..
===
#!/bin/bash
ssh viranka@rmhodtest03.oracle.com <<EOF
echo 'Successfully connected to the server'
pbrun ohsdba -u orthimp7 <<'INNER_EOF'
ls
pwd
id
'INNER_EOF'
EOF
====

Comment: You'll note I wrote `<<'EOF'`, not `<<EOF`, on the outside. The distinction is important -- it ensures that the heredoc is processed literally, rather than having expansions performed.

Comment: ...also, telling `pbrun` to invoke `bash` is important and intentional -- if it passes the inner heredoc's contents to the stdin of anything but a shell, behavior is undefined.

Comment: Also, it's just `INNER_EOF` immediately after a newline to terminate the inner heredoc, not `'INNER_EOF'`; the quotes are a flag to the shell, not part of the sigil itself.

Comment: @user2928822, ...in short, please test the code I gave _exactly_ as I gave it (except for adjusting the username) before trying to make adaptations.

Comment: I have just copy pasted your code on the server..I still face the same issue..worked first time and then failed immediately the next time I execute it.
`#!/bin/bash

ssh ***@*** <<'OUTER_EOF'

echo 'Successfully connected to the server'

pbrun *** -u *** <<'INNER_EOF'

# this is inside both ssh and pbrun

source oraenv

id

INNER_EOF

# this is inside ssh, but not inside pbrun

OUTER_EOF
`
**I couldn't use the bash in the pbrun..it throws me the below error..pbrun7.1.1-05[10313]: Request rejected by pbmasterd **